# How can you call.something #content from a css file when writing HTML

Tags: css, html

I'm a total newbie, and my job requires me to edit web pages occasionally. I was making a quick change right after I woke up with a cold, and the groggy, cold induced state led me to replace an updated file on the server with an out of date one. I've almost fixed it, and only need help with this one thing..

Long story short, I'd like to use something that looks like

```
    .noRight #main {
    width: 100%;
}
```

in the css file and call it in a .asp file, where currently it says

```
  <div id="main">
```

How can one do this? I'm sure this is everywhere on Google, but I don't know what terms to google to get to it.

Also, it's kind of an emergency situation.

Comment: O noes.  No version control?  Has this been fixed yet?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use:

```
#main{width:100%;}
```

This will select any element with the id of `main`. Your previous rule would only select elements with id `main` that are also descendants of an element with the class `noRight`.

### Edit

To apply this on a single page it is probably easiest to include a `style` tag in the `head` e.g.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #main{width:100%;}
</style>
```

This would take precedence over an external style. If you are unable to do this for any reason then another alternative is to add an additional class to `div#main` so that only the instance on that page is matched to your new rule e.g.

```
<div id="main" class="foo">

</div>
```

Then in your stylesheet

```
#main.foo{width:100%;}
```

Note that there is no space between the id and class selectors. This matches elements with the id of `main` and the class `foo`.

Comment: It's one CSS file that all the pages read from, and I need the change only on one page.

Comment: @Daytripper I have updated my answer with a couple of options.

Comment: thanks, I tried the #main{width:100%;} but it didn't work. Maybe I've got it all wrong

Comment: @Daytripper - could you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate your problem? Alternatively, could you provide a link to an accessible page that demonstrates the issue?